# How can I default to placeholder for date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datepicker

Here's the code for my date picker:

```
<div class="editor-field">
                    @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.Date)
                        .HtmlAttributes(ViewBag.Disabled ? (object)new { @class = "formDatePicker", disabled = "disabled", @id = "Date", style = "width:150px", placeholder = "Select Date" } : new { @class = "formDatePicker", @id = "Date", style = "width:150px", placeholder = "Select Date" })
                        .Events(e => e.Open(@<text>function(e){BrowserCompatibility.DisableDatePickerYearsOnSomeBrowsers(e);}</text>))
                        .Format(@HCulture.GetShortDateFormat())
                        .Events(e => e.Change(@<text>function(e){
                            $("#DateString").val($('#Date').val());
                            checkInputValid();
                            }</text>))
                    )
                </div>
```

I tried this solution but it did not work:

```
 var datePicker = $("#Date").data('kendoDatePicker');
 datePicker.input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is:

```
$("#Date").attr("placeholder", "type date");
```

but you can also do:

```
var datePicker = $("#Date").data('kendoDatePicker');
datePicker.element.attr("placeholder", "type date");
```

Remember that `element` in `DatePicker` refers to the original `input` element.

Check both methods in the following code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Date").kendoDatePicker({
  });

  $("#change1").on("click", function() {
    $("#Date").attr("placeholder", "type date 1");
  });
  $("#change2").on("click", function() {
    var datePicker = $("#Date").data('kendoDatePicker');
    datePicker.element.attr("placeholder", "type date 2");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

<button class="k-button" id="change1">Change Method 1</button>
<button class="k-button" id="change2">Change Method 2</button>
<input id="Date" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Comment: You could be right but for some reason, it isn't changing at all with both ways highlighted above.

Comment: I've added a code snippet to show how it works. Of course you cannot have any content in the date for seeing the placeholder.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll give it a try. I'm worried that something else might be affecting it in my code. Could it not be updating because it's disabled or should it not matter?

Comment: I've updated the example setting the input to disable and showing that both methods work.

Comment: I'm sure you're right. I gave you an upvote but this is the only thing that worked for me:  var datePicker = $("#Date").data('kendoDatePicker');
                        datePicker.element.attr('value', '');